# Dúvida entre relacionamentos com Laravel e Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Eu tenho o seguinte modelo, usando laravel 5.8

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz todos os cadastros e estruturei os relacionamentos. Na minha dashboard eu preciso listar em forma de card todos os relatórios de um usuário específico. Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Até o momento eu consigo pegar todos os grupos daquele usuário fazendo isso:

```
$obj = User::with('grupos')->get();
```

Porém, como posso fazer para acessar a outra tabela e chegar no relatório?
Tentei fazer algo parecido com isso:

```
$obj = User::with('grupos', 'relatorios')->get();
```

No entanto, o relacionamento está em outra tabela não consigo listar os dados

#### Modelo usuário

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','cliente_id'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

   public function cliente()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\models\Cliente');
   }

   public function grupos(){
       return $this->belongsToMany("App\models\Grupo", "acessos");
   }
}
```

Comment: Como está sua classe modelo de usuários?

Comment: editei na pergunta principal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você terá que trocar essa linha:

```
$obj = User::with('grupos', 'relatorios')->get();
```

por essa:

```
$obj = User::with('grupos.relatorios')->get();
```

Sendo que no modelo `grupos` tem que ter a declaração de um relacionamento com `relatorios`.

Quando você utiliza a primeira forma, a classe entende que há um relacionamento direto com a outra, mas no seu modelo você só pode fazer o relacionamento com a classe grupos e clientes.

A forma de declaração dessa linha está errada, o correto é:

```
$obj = User::with(['grupos', 'relatorios'])->get();
```

Comment: Show, deu certo. Estão vindos todos os relatórios, porém eu preciso que retorne somente os relatórios de um determinado cliente. Dentro do modelo de Relatorio eu tenho um relacionamento com clientes, seguindo a lógica acima, isso não deveria funcionar? 

 $obj = User::with('grupos.relatorios.cliente')->get()

Pois ainda assim, é retornado todos os relatórios

Comment: Não dessa forma no Eloquente, para isso você terá que mudar a forma de efetuar a busca, pois dessa forma, você está puxando os relatórios do grupo primeiro e depois o cliente, dono daquele relatório.

Comment: Eu reprojetaria o banco, pois cliente tem n usuários, o usuário acesso a n clientes não somente o dele  e os clientes tem n relatórios. Seria isso? Se for o certo é $obj = User::with('grupos.cliente.relatorios')->get()

Comment: Dentro do relatório eu tenho o cliente, buscando a partir do User eu não consigo filtrar o cliente_id do modelo User, com o cliente_id do relatório? Qual seria a outra maneira de fazer isso?

Comment: Eu não sei se estou pensando grande de mais para o seu projeto, mas segue um link do modelo de tabelas que estou pensando https://drive.google.com/open?id=10tOuh5iXeyq3U7TEzNYDxIO4p9Cf4ai_

Comment: Entendi, mas nesse caso você só colocou o relacionamento entre Cliente e Grupo, correto? no Meu modelo os Grupos seriam para todos os clientes, por isso eu não fiz esse relacionamento. Porém, dessa maneira eu conseguiria obter todos os relatórios por grupo de um usuário filtrando pelo cliente?

Comment: Perdão, te envie um modelo errado. Veja esse aqui: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1U_sdlaqu_-C0HQzrLFRmwPN5CU04gft3, uma duvida, um cliente pode estar em mais de um grupo?

Comment: O cliente não, só o usuário.

O usuário pertence a um cliente. e esse usuário pode estar em mais de um grupo

Comment: cara, valeu pela ajuda... mas tava dando muita dor de cabeça.. Eu consegui resolver sem mexer na estrutura. Só que fiz por queryBuilder. Ainda tenho que entender melhor esses relacionamentos complexos usando o Eloquent

Comment: Tranquilo! Sucesso ai!!